# Using Dokku with Resque

Tags: resque, dokku

Does anyone have experience using resque with dokku?

I've been searching all over and cannot figure out how to setup:
- my Procfile
- the connection between my app and the redis server (I've found the dokku-redis plugin for dokku)

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, link the redis service to your app:

```
dokku redis:link SERVICE_NAME APP_NAME
```

Next, add an entry to your procfile like so:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Finally, scale up your resque workers:

```
dokku ps:scale APP_NAME resque=1
```

Comment: The `resque` Procfile command should also define the queue, e.g. `resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`